# Return a list of all columns in specific tables where the column's value is null or empty for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to modify the following query to return a list of all columns in specific tables (Not all tables in the DB as it does now) where fields are either null or empty.

As far as I understand there is a need to change the cursor declaration to search in specified
tables but an additional change is required to return column names which are empty.

Help would be highly appreciated.

```
declare @tempTable TABLE
(
    TableSchema nvarchar(256),
    TableName nvarchar(256),
    ColumnName sysname,
    NotNullCnt bigint
);

declare @sql nvarchar(4000);
declare @tableSchema nvarchar(256);
declare @tableName nvarchar(256);
declare @columnName sysname;
declare @cnt bigint;

declare columnCursor cursor FOR
    SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE IS_NULLABLE = 'YES';

open columnCursor;

fetch next FROM columnCursor INTO @tableSchema, @tableName, @columnName;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin

    SET @sql = 'select @cnt = COUNT(*) from [' + @tableSchema + '].[' + @tableName +
        '] where [' + @columnName + '] is not null';

    exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@cnt bigint output', @cnt = @cnt output;

    INSERT INTO @tempTable SELECT @tableSchema, @tableName, @columnName, @cnt;

    fetch next FROM columnCursor INTO @tableSchema, @tableName, @columnName;
end

close columnCursor;
deallocate columnCursor;

SELECT * FROM @tempTable WHERE NotNullCnt = 0;
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 management studio.